# git invalid redirect to different host

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, bitbucket

Hi I just want to share the solution for a time consuming problem.
The problem was that I was unable to sync my git project from bitbucket.

Visual studio 2013 kept telling me that "Detailed message: invalid redirect to different host"

The reason for the problem in my case was, that I had cloned the project from the source

```
remote.originurl = https://[username]@bitbucket.com/[account]/[projectname]
```

But visual studio was redirected by bitbucket to the url when trying sync

```
https://[username]@bitbucket.org.
```

So by changing the .git/config remote.originurl to

```
remote.originurl = https://[username]@bitbucket.org/[account]/[projectname]
```

solved the problem.

Comment: Why were you using "bitbucket.com" in the first place? The UI never lists that for any repo in the URL.

Comment: It was a glitch from my side, which caused me troubles. I know it was my own fault, so I'm just sharing the solution on such problem, which wasn't described anywhere else.

Comment: No problem. It seems a bit strange that VS can't handle redirection, though.